# validation always showing enter all fields

Tags: php

The problem is that whenever I am loading the page, I am always getting enter all fields, is there anyway to bypass that whenever I load page for the first time.

```
<form action="brand_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="file">Filename(logo):</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>

<br>Brand:<input type="text" name="brand">
<br>Serial No.:<input type="text" name="serial_number">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">


<?php
if (isset ($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['brand']) && isset($_POST['serial_number']) && !empty($_POST['brand']) && !empty($_POST['serial_number'])){
{
  echo 'do something';
}
else
{
  echo '<br>enter all fields';
}
?>

</form>
```

Comment: Separate out your `if` statement into two. Have the first as `if (isset ($_POST['submit'])` to see if the form has been submitted; and if so, include the rest of your code.

Comment: i have broken down the code into two 'if's :). thnks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the request method is post

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if (isset ($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['brand']) && isset($_POST['serial_number']) && !empty($_POST['brand']) && !empty($_POST['serial_number'])){
{
  echo 'do something';
}
else
{
  echo '<br>enter all fields';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `php` code should be in `brand_upload.php`,not in this file.

Comment: This file may be brand_upload.php

Comment: if it is , i suggest to separate action and this file , it's more clean

Answer (score 2):

Wrap all your PHP code with:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct order:

1. First, check if submit button is clicked.
2. Then, check if `brand` and `serial_number` fields are not empty.
3. Finally, print the result.

---

```
if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){
    if (!empty($_POST['brand']) && !empty($_POST['serial_number'])){
        echo 'do something';      
    }else{
        echo '<br>enter all fields';      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is displaying enter all fields because you are checking if your fields are filled when you first load the page. You should check the form validation in your brand_upload.php.

Comment: Are you sure this file isn't brand_upload.php?